# Probability of getting exactly a single pair of cards from a hand of 5 cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If one has a standard deck of 52 cards and I pick 5 cards. What is the probability that I exactly have exactly one pair of cards (meaning of the same rank: aces and aces, kings and kings, etc)?

The book I am reading shows the following approach:

$$ P(\text{four of a kind}) = \frac{13 \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{12}{3} \times 4^3}{\binom{52}{5}} $$

I understand this approach till the $4^3$ part, which made me wonder why an approach like this wouldn't work?

$$P(\text{four of a kind}) = \frac{52\times 3 \times 48 \times 44 \times 40}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Where I thought of it using the fundamental theory of counting:
52 is the number of cards we can chose from. After choosing from those 52, there are 3 cards left from that rank which we will choose another from. Afterwards, we are left with 48 cards (because we can no longer chose from the rank we picked at the start) from which we pick a card. Then 44 because again we cannot pick from the previous rank or that would be another pair. Then 40 choices for the same reason.

I realize there is something at fault with my reasoning but I can't quite determine what it is. Can anyone help me understand the error in my thinking?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please correct the two expressions. the denominator is clearly wrong in both of them.

Comment: @Haris Apologies friend, it has now been corrected

Comment: oh, no problem at all

Comment: Your approach with $\dfrac{52\times 3\times 48\times 44\times 40}{\binom{52}{5}}$ is wrong for the reason that it incorrectly applies some sort of significance to whether a non-pair card was selected "first" vs "second" or "third".  You would need to divide by $3!$ to account for this, and indeed you should find that your answer matches the book's answer after this correction.

Comment: @JMoravitz After a division by 3!, my probability becomes a 0.845 instead of a 0.43.

Comment: @JMoravitz It seems that my approach is faulty from the start. Even then, after correction, it still results in an incredibly small number that is <0.43

Comment: Whether we talk about hands where cards are with order relevant or hands where order is irrelevant needs to be consistent between numerator and denominator.  The denominator of $\binom{52}{5}$ is for hands where order is not relevant.  In your answer you have order mattering in a number of places, keep looking to see where.  $52\times 3$ it matters whether the card was the "first seen" in the pair vs "second seen", so there's another factor of $2$ to get rid of.  We do have $\dfrac{52\times 3\times 48\times 44\times 40}{\binom{52}{5}\times 3!\times 2!} = \dfrac{352}{833}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a bunch, that sort of clears up my confusion. But how can I determine generally if order matters or not in my terms in the numerator?

Comment: By checking whether changing the order of answers to the questions "what did i pick here" gives possibly the same result.  For instance here, the answers in the order $A\spadesuit,~A\clubsuit,2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ was counted separately than $A\clubsuit,~A\spadesuit,2\heartsuit,3\heartsuit,4\heartsuit$ and also counted separately than $A\clubsuit,~A\spadesuit,2\heartsuit,4\heartsuit,3\heartsuit$.  In general, splitting things into separate steps in multiplication principle might accidentally give importance to the order in which the steps are performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $4^3$ is referring to the following.

After we have chosen the three denominations (out of the twelve remaining), there are $4$ cards for each denomination. So, the number of ways in which you can choose the three cards is $4 \times 4 \times 4$ (one $4$ for each denomination).

The problem with your thinking is that when forming your numerator, you proceed as if order matters. While for the denominator, it doesn't - $52$ choose $5$.

To give you an example, when choosing the last $3$ cards in your solution, AKQ would be considered different from QAK.

To compensate for the ordering, you will need to divide by $3!$ for the three non-pair cards and $2!$ for the pair.

Comment: But why would an approach such as mine result in an incorrect answer?

Comment: @Renadil edited to answer to include that. sorry!

Comment: So therefore, I can simply divide out the order from the numerator?

Comment: yes, divide it by $3!$ (for the last $3$ cards) and $2!$ for the pair.